# Angularjs display expression in curly braces as text

Tags: angularjs

I need to display some text on the page which looks exactly as Angularjs 
expression in curly braces:

```
{{some_text}}
```

But this is just a text and should not denote bindings. 
Unfortunately, I cannot modify this text somehow so need to solve this particular issue.

This text is echo'ed by the means of php on the page and is showing inside ng-controller section.

I will appreciate any ideas.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So basically what i get from the question is you want to print {{ some_text }} on the page right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the **[`$interpolateProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/%24interpolateProvider)**'s start- and end-symbols (e.g. instead of `{{` and `}}`, you could set them to `{[` and `]}` (or whatever)).

Alternatively, you could put it inside an element with the **[`ngNonBindable`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable)** directive, which Angular won't touch (this is probably the best option if there are no other constraints or requirements prohibiting it).

---

BTW, **[`v1.3.0-beta.10`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-130-beta10-excessive-clarification-2014-05-23)** introduced a way to escape the start- and end-symbols (e.g. something like `\\{\\{` `\\}\\}`) and there is a lengthy discussion regarding the reasoning of such a feature (and several work-arounds) **[here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5601)**.

Comment: Thank you so much and thanks for the different options. $interpolateProvider is exactly my case as this text is echo'ed on many pages.

Answer (score 1):

ngNonBindable directive Is a definite solution. As shown Below.

```
<div>Normal: {{1 + 2}}</div>
<div ng-non-bindable>Ignored: {{1 + 2}}</div>
```